# iframe-Element in Angular 5 get filled with the Angular instead of the provided src

Tags: javascript, html, angular, iframe

I have a simple application built with Angular 5. 
In this application are 2 HTML-documents.

The first one (test.html) looks like this:

```html
<h1>This Iframe works</h1>
```

The second file (app.component.html) looks like this:

```html
<iframe src="test/test.html"></iframe>
<p>Test under Iframe</p>
```

When starting the application it looks like this:

[image]

The Application will load 2 other iframes inside of my iframe-Element. But the code thats inside the "src"-document wont show up.

How can i fix this error?

Im currently using Angular 5, Node.js 9.4.0, NPM 5.6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the error: I put the .html file into the src-Folder, but after moving the document to the assets-folder everything worked fine!